Give a bijection from Z \ N to Z
I have to give a bijection from the set of integers excluding the natural numbers, to the set of integers. Please help me with this. I mapped 0 to 0 and all even negative integers to their half (-2 to -1, -4 to -2 and so on) Now I want to map the odd negative integers to the positive integers, but I can't figure out the function.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this is not a do my work for me site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help,

What stops you to map $-1,-3,-5,-7,\dots$ to $1,2,3,4,\dots$?

I want to give a function, when x is a negative odd integer. I can not figure that out.

Though not extremely difficult, you don't need to "give a function" (a formula). Just enumerating backwards the negative odd integers gives you the desired bijection.

Okay, the bijection is now given but how do I write this down as solution?

As @AnneBauval comments, you do not need a formula to describe your function. Writing it as you did with the $\ldots$ ellipsis should be perfectly satisfactory. (I would accept it as an answer. Your instructor may require a formula, but I think they shouldn't.)

First of all, 0 is even, so mapping 0 to its half results in 0. If you want to map a negative odd integer to a positive integer, you can do something to the odd number to make it even and then cut it in half like you did with the even negative integers. (What can you do?)
The bigger issue is that you need a bijection, specifically you need every integer in $\mathbb{Z}$ to be mapped to by some integer in $\mathbb{N}$. I recommend defining a piecewise function where you map negative even/odd numbers to positive/negative integers.
Also, not sure from the question, but you might need to prove that your function is indeed a bijection. Do you know how to do this?

Would -( (x-1) / 2) be correct?

Yeah, that works. Now try putting everything together in a piecewise function.
